# Chome and Firefox prevents the modification of a derived class's prototype in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, coffeescript

I've recently been trying to learn CoffeeScript. As I'm trying to understand the inheritance system in CoffeeScript I came into a bit of a dilemma. I've tried this in Chrome 40, Internet Explorer 11, and Firefox 36 and only Internet Exporer 11 performs in the way that I would expect.

This code in CoffeeScript:

```
class Muppet
    constructor: (@age, @hobby) -> # Why is this function empty?
    answerNanny: -> "Everything's cool!"

class SwedishChef extends Muppet
    constructor: (age, hobby, @mood) ->
        super(age, hobby)
    cook: -> 'Mmmm soup!'
```

Produces this code in JavaScript:

```
var Muppet, SwedishChef,
__hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
__extends = function(child, parent) { 
    for (var key in parent) { 
        if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; 
    } 
    function ctor() { 
        this.constructor = child; 
    } 
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; 
    child.prototype = new ctor(); 
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; 
};

Muppet = (function() {
    function Muppet(age, hobby) {
        this.age = age;
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }

    Muppet.prototype.answerNanny = function() {
        return "Everything's cool!";
    };

    return Muppet;
})();

SwedishChef = (function(_super) {
    __extends(SwedishChef, _super);

    function SwedishChef(age, hobby, mood) {
        this.mood = mood;
        SwedishChef.__super__.constructor.call(this, age, hobby);
    }

    SwedishChef.prototype.cook = function() {
        return 'Mmmm soup!';
    };

    return SwedishChef;
})(Muppet)
```

Here is the console output I get in Chrome:

```
muppet = new Muppet(3,4)
-> Muppet {age: 3, hobby: 4, answerNanny: function}
chef = new SwedishChef(3,4,5)
-> SwedishChef {mood: 5, age: 3, hobby: 4, constructor: function, cook: function…}
Muppet.prototype.food = "potato"
-> "potato"
muppet
-> Muppet {age: 3, hobby: 4, answerNanny: function, food: "potato"}
chef
-> SwedishChef {mood: 5, age: 3, hobby: 4, constructor: function, cook: function…}
SwedishChef.prototype.food = "fish"
-> "fish"
chef
-> SwedishChef {mood: 5, age: 3, hobby: 4, constructor: function, cook: function…}
```

Now it seems that if I remove the last three lines in the `__extends` function, specifically:

```
ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; 
child.prototype = new ctor(); 
child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child;
```

In all browsers I can freely modify the prototypes of `Muppet` and `SwedishChef` independently. When those lines are put back I cannot in any way modify the prototype of the derived class `SwedishChef` In Chrome. This includes modifying the prototype of the base class `Muppet`. The modifications do not propagate to child classes. In Firefox I can't modify the prototype of either base class or child class.

It seems from those three lines that the intent was to make child classes have their prototype bound to the parent class's prototype but this is only apparent in Internet Explorer 11.

Simply put, I'd like to know where my error is in all of this. I understand that browser could have strange implementation quirks sometimes but I'd like to rule out any errors I've made in this. Thanks to all who put their time and effort into reading and answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just reading your console output incorrectly, as in, the property is there, but it's either hidden behind the ellipsis (`...`) or it's on the `__proto__` property and you need to expand that.

However, I am curious why you are trying to modify the prototypes after the fact rather than include them in the class definitions. Isn't the one of the main points of CoffeeScript classes that you don't need to tinker with their internal workings?

This is the compiled version of your code, including the part you carried out in the console. It works fine in FireFox and Chrome:

```js
var Muppet, SwedishChef, chef, muppet,
  extend = function(child, parent) {
    for (var key in parent) {
      if (hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key];
    }

    function ctor() {
      this.constructor = child;
    }
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new ctor();
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
    return child;
  },
  hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty;

Muppet = (function() {
  function Muppet(age1, hobby1) {
    this.age = age1;
    this.hobby = hobby1;
  }

  Muppet.prototype.answerNanny = function() {
    return "Everything's cool!";
  };

  return Muppet;

})();

SwedishChef = (function(superClass) {
  extend(SwedishChef, superClass);

  function SwedishChef(age, hobby, mood) {
    this.mood = mood;
    SwedishChef.__super__.constructor.call(this, age, hobby);
  }

  SwedishChef.prototype.cook = function() {
    return 'Mmmm soup!';
  };

  return SwedishChef;

})(Muppet);

muppet = new Muppet(3, 4);

chef = new SwedishChef(3, 4, 5);

Muppet.prototype.food = "potato";

console.dir(muppet);

SwedishChef.prototype.food = "fish";

console.dir(chef);
```

Comment: I feel very stupid now. Thank you! Truth is this these are snippets from [CoffeeScript Koans](https://github.com/sleepyfox/coffeescript-koans). I was kind of confused as to how I wasn't able to modify prototypes of objects as I would in normal JavaScript. I now understand that coffeescript classes are meant for something else. I'll try to be more observant next time I read console outputs :)

Comment: Also I apologize for not being able to upvote you. I don't have enough reputation yet :(